# Change JavaScript scroll top to a id or class rather than body

Tags: javascript, actionscript-2, onscroll, onscrolllistener

I have a side menu that sticks to the top of the page. rather than using the body to tell the position can I change it to a div, call or id.

**My current code**
this code tells the side menu to position itself according to a class once i have scrolled 40px from the top of the page, how do i change it so its 40px from a ID or class?

```
 window.onscroll = function () {onScrollNav()};

function onScrollNav() {
   if (document.body.scrollTop > 40 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 40) {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").className = "sidenavScroll";
        console.log("you hit 40px !!");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").className = "sidenavScrollReset";
        console.log("you back to 0 !!");
    }
}
```

Comment: so reference the element, determine the position, figure out the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to get the scroll position, the offset of the element with the ID in question and lastly do some quick maths.

```
var elOffset = document.getElementById('<ID HERE>').getBoundingClientRect();
function onScrollNav() {
    var diff = (document.documentElement.scrollTop - elOffset.top);
    if (diff > 40) {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").className = "sidenavScroll";
        console.log("you hit 40px offset from the element with ID!!");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").className = "sidenavScrollReset";
        console.log("you back to 0 !!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ill try this